# Google Sites - simple content and background picture

Tags: html, image, google-sites

I'm trying to set up Google Sites for my own personal website:

```
<html>
<head>
<title>...</title>
</head>
    <body background="page_bg.png" text="#000000" bgcolor="#333333">
        <div align="center"><img src="content.jpg" border="0" alt=""></div>
    </body>
</html>
```

So all I want is a background picture (I accomplished to do this under settings) and only one picture in the middle of the site itself. I was trying to get rid of all the gimmicks (such as the sidebar, shadows of the frame, etc.) but I failed. Is it even possible to do this?

The reason I use Sites is, because the web address "https://sites.google.com/site/my_name_here/" is clear, it's free and it makes my site appear in the google search.

---

edit, my solution: I found a template called "Blank Template (Black)" which didn't contain anything (no sidebar, etc). I added my own background picture, inserted my content.jpg and done.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

My solution: I found a template called "Blank Template (Black)" which didn't contain anything (no sidebar, etc). I added my own background picture, inserted my content.jpg and done.

Answer (score 0):

I guess you have to use something like:

```
<body style="background:#333333 url('page_bg.png'); color=#000000;">
<div style="text-align:center;"><img src="content.jpg" border="0" alt=""></div>
</body>
```

Comment: Sorry, I probably didn't explain it well. What I meant was: are there e.g. any Google Sites templates that are purely empty so that I can add my content.jpg and my background picture? Or is it possible to edit the overall html-file of my site and then do what you suggested?

Answer (score 0):

Oh ok, right! I think you cannot add your own styles using html/css. But if you go to "Managing Web site" there is a "Colors and fonts" option, and there you make you own customization for some elements, like select a different background color.
Is that what you're looking for Thomas?

Answer (score -1):

"img"<src=content.png-background fill> "content.png" set= full

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! While this code may answer the question, providing additional context regarding *why* and/or *how* this code answers the question improves its long-term value.